# Pimcore object bricks are manually added by the user

Tags: pimcore

Pimcore doesnt allow inherit of product object - in the sense that oop allows. So a solution is to use object bricks to abstract the specifics of the child* product e.g. Sneaker vs Shirt. (correct?)

However, I do not want for my users to have to create a product and then associate the specific object brick manually in order to make an e.g. sneaker. Ideally they would click "create sneaker" and that would assign the correct object brick.

How would I go about the above?

Comment: You'd probably have to implement this solution yourself. You'll need to create plugin and write some ExtJS code.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial/example - start to finish of a pimcore plugin? I see random code all over the web, but no good example e.g. where does the plugin code even go? I am a programmer, so not scared of code - I just need a catalyst. Thanks -

Comment: Go to Your Extras > Extensions and click "Create new plugin skeleton". It will create all files needed by Pimcore for Your new plugin. https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/UI+Development+and+JS+Hooks Here You have some info on JS Hooks, and there https://github.com/pimcore-extensions are some plugins where You can see how code is done.

Comment: @DavidLatty I suppose you don't speak German? If you do, Basilicom has a nice primer on creating plugins for pimcore -> https://basilicom.de/blog/entwicklung-eines-pimcore-plugins. If not, maybe google translate can help you out, or I could translate the post for you if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin code goes under /plugins/YourPlugin. You can create a skeleton plugin by Extras -> Manage Extensions and the button Create new plugin skeleton.

I did something similar some time ago where i overrode the postsave(don't remember the name) event and checked if the object was of the specific class. In that case we added some code where emails was to be sent out after the save.

I guess you can find some event where you can attach and add some logic to set the the type of the brick.